# calendar reminder not gives notifiaction when it is time

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I successfully create a calendar event with reminder in my app, it works well in AVD but when I install the apk on my own phone the reminder doesn't work.
I am sure that I have granted the Calendar to give notification for when I create the event directly through system calendar, the reminder works.
Here is my code for creating a calendar event:

```
public static long addCalendarEvent(Context context, String title, String description, long startTime, int repeatTime) {
        if (context == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int calId = checkAndAddCalendarAccount(context); 
        if (calId < 0) { 
            return 0;
        }

        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calId);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTime);
        long endTime = getNowTime(new Date(startTime)) + 86400000L;
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        String daily = "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=" + repeatTime;
        
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, daily);
        Uri newEvent = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(CALENDER_EVENT_URL), event); 
        if (newEvent == null) { 
            return 0;
        }


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, ContentUris.parseId(newEvent));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(CALENDER_REMINDER_URL), values);
        if (uri == null) { 
            return 0;
        }
        return ContentUris.parseId(newEvent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I finally know what's wrong.  The field ***CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES*** must be set to 0 for its default value is -1

[image]

It looks like this in code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, ContentUris.parseId(newEvent));
values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES,0);
```